# Python Variable Naming vs C++ Variable Naming

Tags: python

I am starting to get deeper in learning Python and having a great time doing it but there is one thing that is bothering me. Why is it in C++ answers/tutorial/books are variables namedLikeThis and in Python they are named_like_this?

Is this just personal preference or is it a convention that should be followed for readability/clarity sake? Not a big deal but I don't want to be the weird guy writing annoying looking code.

Comment: The topic is better for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: The [Style Guide for Python Code a.k.a. PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) is widely accepted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

People writing Python generally follow PEP8 (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @thebjorn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20597637/1426065), from [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> ### [Package and Module Names](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id30)
>
> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be
> used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages
> should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of
> underscores is discouraged.

...

> ### [Class Names](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id31)
>
> Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.

...

> ### [Function Names](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id34)
>
> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility.

...

> ### [Method Names and Instance Variables](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id36)
>
> Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by
> underscores as necessary to improve readability.

...

> ### [Constants](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id37)
>
> Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all
> capital letters with underscores separating words.

---

I definitely recommend reading PEP8 in its entirety, not only the naming conventions part. You'll be a much better Pythonista for it :)